# reverse print an immutable linked list with less than O(n) space

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, linked-list

Working on this problem, and my ideas is doing recursive and during each recursion, reverse print 2nd half of the linkedlist, then reverse print 1st half of the linkedlist. So that additional space is `O(log n)` -- which is for additional space for recursive stack, but it is more than O(n) for time (O(n log n) - combined calls on each of (log n) levels of recursion iterate whole list to cut each portion in half).

Are there algorithms that achieve the same goal - reverse print an immutable single linked list with less than O(n) space and at most O(n) time?

**Source code** (Python 2.7):

```
class LinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, value, next_node):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = next_node
    @staticmethod
    def reverse_print(list_head, list_tail):
        if not list_head:
            return
        if not list_head.next_node:
            print list_head.value
            return
        if list_head == list_tail:
            print list_head.value
            return
        p0 = list_head
        p1 = list_head
        while p1.next_node != list_tail and p1.next_node.next_node != list_tail:
            p1 = p1.next_node
            p1 = p1.next_node
            p0 = p0.next_node
        LinkedListNode.reverse_print(p0.next_node, list_tail)
        LinkedListNode.reverse_print(list_head, p0)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_head = LinkedListNode(4, LinkedListNode(5, LinkedListNode(12, LinkedListNode(1, LinkedListNode(3, None)))))
    LinkedListNode.reverse_print(list_head, None)
```

Comment: If your code is working fine, but you just need ideas to improve it - the best place to ask is [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Why do you make reverse_print a static method? Its first argument is a LinkedListNode. So simply make it a method of LinkedListNode. I also recommend you to ask at codereview.

Comment: What is the time complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: @miracle173, I think my algorithm time complexity is `O(n)`, if not correct, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I will try. Code review is a very good place to ask, but sometimes they only focus on code style other than better (less time/space complexity), it is why I try here first. If you have any ideas on my original question, it will be great. :)

Comment: @miracle173, for your comments -- "So simply make it a method of LinkedListNode", agree and no issues from me. If you have any thoughts on my original question, it will be great.

Comment: Single- or double-linked-list?

Comment: @Raphael reverse printing a double-linked-list is trivial, not worth asking a question about.

Comment: Has anybody told you that what you desire is possible? Because I suspect it isn't, although I can't prove it.

Comment: There is a discussion about this post at meta.stackoverflow.com: [A question about reverse printing a linked list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341183/754550)

Comment: @MarkRansom Are you saying that if I posed the task to first-year students, all of them would get full credit? That would strike me as an ... optimistic prognosis. ;) (FWIW, "trivial" is relative)

Comment: @MarkRansom: It is possible: [O(n) time and O(sqrt(n)) space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41575182/754550)

Comment: I asked if there is a better algorithm at [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68769/print-the-nodes-of-an-immutable-single-linked-list-in-reverse-order)

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, why not first get the length of the linkedlist(O(n)). Create a function to get ith node(O(i)). Then just loop on the length and print (n-i)th node. Space required is constant but the run time is O(n^2).

Answer (score 16):

This is an O(n) time and O(sqrt(n)) space algorithm.
In the second part of the post it will be extended to a linear time and  O(n^(1/t)) space algorithm for an arbitrary positive integer t.

High-level idea: Split the list into sqrt(n) many (almost) equal-sized parts. 
Print the parts one after the other in reverse order using a naive linear-time, linear-space method, from the last to the first.

To store the start nodes of the parts we need an array of size O(sqrt(n)).
To revert a part of size approximately sqrt(n) the naive algorithm needs an array to store references to the node of the part. So the array has a size of O(sqrt(n).

---

One uses two arrays (`lsa` and `ssa`)of size `k=[sqrt(n)]+1 =O(sqrt(n))`
(lsa ... large step array, ssa .. small step array)

> **Phase 1:** (if the size of the linked list is not known find out n, its length):
>       move through the list from start  to end and count the elements of the list, this needs n steps
>
> **Phase 2:**
>       Store each k-th node of the single linked list in the array `lsa`. This needs n steps.
>
> **Phase 3:** 
>   Process the `lsa`list in reverse order. Print each part in reverse order
>   This takes also n steps

So the runtime of the algorithm is 3n = O(n) and its pace is about 2*sqrt(n) = O(sqrt(n)).

This is a Python 3.5 implementation :

```
import cProfile
import math

class LinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, value, next_node):
        self.value = value
        self._next_node = next_node

    def next_node(self):
        return(self._next_node)

    def reverse_print(self):
        # Phase 1
        n=0
        node=self
        while node:
            n+=1
            node=node.next_node()
        k=int(n**.5)+1

        # Phase 2
        i=0
        node=self
        lsa=[node]
        while node:
            i+=1
            if i==k:
                lsa.append(node)
                i=0
            last_node=node
            node=node.next_node()
        if i>0:
            lsa.append(last_node)

        # Phase 3
        start_node=lsa.pop()
        print(start_node.value)
        while lsa:
            last_printed_node=start_node
            start_node=lsa.pop()
            node=start_node
            ssa=[]
            while node!=last_printed_node:
                ssa.append(node)
                node=node.next_node()

            ssa.reverse()
            for node in ssa:
                print(node.value)


    @classmethod
    def create_testlist(nodeclass, n):
        ''' creates a list of n elements with values 1,...,n'''
        first_node=nodeclass(n,None)
        for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
            second_node=first_node
            first_node=nodeclass(i,second_node)
        return(first_node)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n=1000
    cProfile.run('LinkedListNode.create_testlist(n).reverse_print()')
    print('estimated number of calls of next_node',3*n)
```

It prints the following output (at the end is the output of the profiler that shows the number of function calls):

```
>>> 
 RESTART: print_reversed_list3.py 
1000
999
998
...
4
3
2
1
         101996 function calls in 2.939 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.939    2.939 <string>:1(<module>)
     2000    0.018    0.000    2.929    0.001 PyShell.py:1335(write)
        1    0.003    0.003    2.938    2.938 print_reversed_list3.py:12(reverse_print)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 print_reversed_list3.py:49(create_testlist)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 print_reversed_list3.py:5(__init__)
     2999    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 print_reversed_list3.py:9(next_node)    
   ...

estimated number of calls of next_node 3000
>>>
```

The number of calls to next_node() is 3000 as expected

---

Instead of using the naive O(m) space algorithm to print the sublist of length m in reversed order one can use this O(sqrt(m)) space algorithm. But we  must find the right balance between the number of sublists and the length of the sublists:

Phase 2:
Split the simple linked list into n^(1/3) sublists of length n^(2/3). The startnodes of these sublists are stored in an array of length n^(1/3)

Phase 3: Print each sublist of length m=n^(2/3) in reversed order using the O(sqrt(m)) space algorithm. Because m=n^(2/3) we need m^(1/2)=n^(1/3) space.

We now have a O(n^(1/3)) space algorithm that needs 4n time and so is still O(n)

We can repeat this again by splitting into n^(1/4) sublists of length m=n^(3/4) tha are processed by the O(m^(1/3)) = O(n^(1/4)) space algorithm that needs 5n=O(n) time.

We can repeat this again and again and arrive a the following statement:

**The immutable simply linked list of size n can be printed in reversed order using t*n^(1/t)=O(n^(1/t)) space and (t+1)n =O(n) time where t is an arbitrary positive integer**

---

If one does not fix t but selects t depending from n such that n^(1/t)) about 2, the smallest useful array size, then this results in the O(nlog(n)) time and O(log(n)) space algorithm described by the OP.

If one chooses t=1 this results in the O(n) time and O(n) space naive algorithm.

---

Here is an implementation of the algorithm

```
import cProfile
import math
import time

class LinkedListNode:
    '''
    single linked list node
    a node has a value and a successor node
    '''
    stat_counter=0
    stat_curr_space=0
    stat_max_space=0
    stat_max_array_length=0
    stat_algorithm=0
    stat_array_length=0
    stat_list_length=0
    stat_start_time=0

    do_print=True
    def __init__(self, value, next_node):
        self.value = value
        self._next_node = next_node


    def next_node(self):
        self.stat_called_next_node()
        return(self._next_node)

    def print(self):
        if type(self).do_print:
            print(self.value)

    def print_tail(self):
        node=self
        while node:
            node.print()
            node=node.next_node()

    def tail_info(self):
        list_length=0
        node=self
        while node:
            list_length+=1
            last_node=node
            node=node.next_node()
        return((last_node,list_length))


    def retrieve_every_n_th_node(self,step_size,list_length):
        ''' for a list a of size list_length retrieve a pair there the first component 
        is an array with the nodes 
        [a[0],a[k],a[2*k],...,a[r*k],a[list_length-1]]]
        and the second component is list_length-1-r*k
        and 
        '''
        node=self
        arr=[]
        s=step_size
        index=0
        while index<list_length:
            if s==step_size:
                arr.append(node)
                s=1
            else:
                s+=1
            last_node=node
            node=node.next_node()
            index+=1
        if s!=1:
            last_s=s-1
            arr.append(last_node)
        else:
            last_s=step_size
        return(arr,last_s)


    def reverse_print(self,algorithm=0):
        (last_node,list_length)=self.tail_info()
        assert(type(algorithm)==int)
        if algorithm==1:
            array_length=list_length
        elif algorithm==0:
            array_length=2
        elif algorithm>1:
            array_length=math.ceil(list_length**(1/algorithm))
            if array_length<2:
                array_length=2
        else:
            assert(False)
        assert(array_length>=2)
        last_node.print()
        self.stat_init(list_length=list_length,algorithm=algorithm,array_length=array_length)
        self._reverse_print(list_length,array_length)
        assert(LinkedListNode.stat_curr_space==0)
        self.print_statistic()



    def _reverse_print(self,list_length,array_length):
        '''
        this is the core procedure  of the algorithm
            if the list fits into the array
                store it in te array an print the array in reverse order
            else
                split the list in 'array_length' sublists and store
                    the startnodes of the sublists in he array
                _reverse_print array in reverse order
        '''
        if list_length==3 and array_length==2: # to avoid infinite loop
            array_length=3
        step_size=math.ceil(list_length/array_length)
        if step_size>1: # list_length>array_length:
            (supporting_nodes,last_step_size)=self.retrieve_every_n_th_node(step_size,list_length)
            self.stat_created_array(supporting_nodes)
            supporting_nodes.reverse()
            supporting_nodes[1]._reverse_print(last_step_size+1,array_length)
            for node in supporting_nodes[2:]:
                node._reverse_print(step_size+1,array_length)
            self.stat_removed_array(supporting_nodes)
        else:
            assert(step_size>0)
            (adjacent_nodes,last_step_size)=self.retrieve_every_n_th_node(1,list_length)
            self.stat_created_array(adjacent_nodes)
            adjacent_nodes.reverse()
            for node in adjacent_nodes[1:]:
                node.print()
            self.stat_removed_array(adjacent_nodes)

    # statistics functions

    def stat_init(self,list_length,algorithm,array_length):
        '''
        initializes the counters
        and starts the stop watch
        '''
        type(self)._stat_init(list_length,algorithm,array_length)

    @classmethod
    def _stat_init(cls,list_length,algorithm,array_length):
        cls.stat_curr_space=0
        cls.stat_max_space=0
        cls.stat_counter=0
        cls.stat_max_array_length=0
        cls.stat_array_length=array_length
        cls.stat_algorithm=algorithm
        cls.stat_list_length=list_length
        cls.stat_start_time=time.time()

    def print_title(self):
        '''
        prints the legend and the caption for the statistics values
        '''
        type(self).print_title()

    @classmethod
    def print_title(cls):
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('space','maximal number of array space for'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('',     'pointers to the list nodes, that'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('',     'is needed'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('time', 'number of times the method next_node,'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('',     'that retrievs the successor of a node,'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('',     'was called'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('alg',  'algorithm that was selected:'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('',     '0:   array size is 2'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('',     '1:   array size is n, naive algorithm'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('',     't>1: array size is n^(1/t)'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('arr',  'dimension of the arrays'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('sz',  'actual maximal dimension of the arrays'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('n',    'list length'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('log',    'the logarithm to base 2 of n'))
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('n log n',    'n times the logarithm to base 2 of n'))               
        print('   {0:10s} {1:s}'.format('seconds',    'the runtime of the program in seconds'))               

        print()
        print('{0:>10s} {1:>10s} {2:>4s} {3:>10s} {4:>10s} {5:>10s} {6:>5s} {7:>10s} {8:>10s}'
              .format('space','time','alg','arr','sz','n','log', 'n log n','seconds'))

    @classmethod
    def print_statistic(cls):
        '''
        stops the stop watch and prints the statistics for the gathered counters
        '''
        run_time=time.time()-cls.stat_start_time
        print('{0:10d} {1:10d} {2:4d} {3:10d} {4:10d} {5:10d} {6:5d} {7:10d} {8:10.2f}'.format(
            cls.stat_max_space,cls.stat_counter,cls.stat_algorithm,
            cls.stat_array_length,cls.stat_max_array_length,cls.stat_list_length,
            int(math.log2(cls.stat_list_length)),int(cls.stat_list_length*math.log2(cls.stat_list_length)),
            run_time
            ))

    def stat_called_next_node(self):
        '''
        counter: should be called
        if the next node funtion is called
        '''
        type(self)._stat_called_next_node()

    @classmethod
    def _stat_called_next_node(cls):
        cls.stat_counter+=1

    def stat_created_array(self,array):
        '''
        counter: should be called
        after an array was created and filled
        '''
        type(self)._stat_created_array(array)

    @classmethod
    def _stat_created_array(cls,array):
        cls.stat_curr_space+=len(array)
        if cls.stat_curr_space> cls.stat_max_space:
            cls.stat_max_space=cls.stat_curr_space
        if (len(array)>cls.stat_max_array_length):
            cls.stat_max_array_length=len(array)

    def stat_removed_array(self,array):
        '''
        counter: should be called
        before an array can be removed
        '''
        type(self)._stat_removed_array(array)

    @classmethod
    def _stat_removed_array(cls,array):
        cls.stat_curr_space-=len(array)

    @classmethod
    def create_testlist(nodeclass, n):
        '''
        creates a single linked list of
        n elements with values 1,...,n
        '''
        first_node=nodeclass(n,None)
        for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
            second_node=first_node
            first_node=nodeclass(i,second_node)
        return(first_node)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #cProfile.run('LinkedListNode.create_testlist(n).reverse_print()')
    n=100000
    ll=LinkedListNode.create_testlist(n)
    LinkedListNode.do_print=False
    ll.print_title()
    ll.reverse_print(1)
    ll.reverse_print(2)
    ll.reverse_print(3)
    ll.reverse_print(4)
    ll.reverse_print(5)
    ll.reverse_print(6)
    ll.reverse_print(7)
    ll.reverse_print(0)
```

And here are some results

```
   space      maximal number of array space for
              pointers to the list nodes, that
              is needed
   time       number of times the method next_node,
              that retrievs the successor of a node,
              was called
   alg        algorithm that was selected:
              0:   array size is 2
              1:   array size is n, naive algorithm
              t>1: array size is n^(1/t)
   arr        dimension of the arrays
   sz         actual maximal dimension of the arrays
   n          list length
   log        the logarithm to base 2 of n
   n log n    n times the logarithm to base 2 of n
   seconds    the runtime of the program in seconds

     space       time  alg        arr         sz          n   log    n log n    seconds
    100000     100000    1     100000     100000     100000    16    1660964       0.17
       635     200316    2        317        318     100000    16    1660964       0.30
       143     302254    3         47         48     100000    16    1660964       0.44
        75     546625    4         18         19     100000    16    1660964       0.99
        56     515989    5         11         12     100000    16    1660964       0.78
        47     752976    6          7          8     100000    16    1660964       1.33
        45     747059    7          6          7     100000    16    1660964       1.23
        54    1847062    0          2          3     100000    16    1660964       3.02
```

and

```
   space      maximal number of array space for
              pointers to the list nodes, that
              is needed
   time       number of times the method next_node,
              that retrievs the successor of a node,
              was called
   alg        algorithm that was selected:
              0:   array size is 2
              1:   array size is n, naive algorithm
              t>1: array size is n^(1/t)
   arr        dimension of the arrays
   sz         actual maximal dimension of the arrays
   n          list length
   log        the logarithm to base 2 of n
   n log n    n times the logarithm to base 2 of n
   seconds    the runtime of the program in seconds

     space       time  alg        arr         sz          n   log    n log n    seconds
   1000000    1000000    1    1000000    1000000    1000000    19   19931568       1.73
      2001    3499499    2       1000       1001    1000000    19   19931568       7.30
       302    4514700    3        100        101    1000000    19   19931568       8.58
       131    4033821    4         32         33    1000000    19   19931568       5.69
        84    6452300    5         16         17    1000000    19   19931568      11.04
        65    7623105    6         10         11    1000000    19   19931568      13.26
        59    7295952    7          8          9    1000000    19   19931568      11.07
        63   21776637    0          2          3    1000000    19   19931568      34.39
```

Comment: Good job... I was just rushing to write the same algorithm but you beat me :)

Comment: Nice ideas miracle173, vote up, a dumb question, why do you choose value as `k=int(n**.5)+1`?

Comment: it is necessary that k^2>=n, so math.ceil(n**.5) would be sufficient but I didn't want to import math. So I used int(n**.5)+1 which is equal to  so math.ceil(n**.5) except if n is a square number. In this case we have used int(n**.5)+1 > math.ceil(n**.5)

Comment: I asked if there is a better algorithm at [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68769/print-the-nodes-of-an-immutable-single-linked-list-in-reverse-order)

Comment: @miracle173, I tried to use `math.floor(math.sqrt(count))`, it seems work as well, do you see any issues, or pros/cons comparing (your formula in your post) to using `math.floor(math.sqrt(count))`?

Comment: @LinMa No, not in Python, because the arrays are dynamically. if you select a small value (which is used to select the numbe of points that are appended to lsa) then the ssa will become larger. Better use the second program. reverse_print(2) will print the statistics (including array sizes) of the algorithm with O(n**.5) arra size.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ends of the spectrum in terms of space/time requirements for this problem:

1. O(n) space, O(n) time
2. O(1) space, O(n^2) time

Since you don't care about the O(n) space solution, let's look at the other one:

```
def reverse_print(LL):
    length = 0
    curr = LL
    while curr:
        length += 1
        curr = curr.next

    for i in range(length, 0, -1):
        curr = LL
        for _ in range(i):
            curr = curr.next
        print(curr.value)
```

Of course, you could do this in O(n) time and 0 space if you chose to turn this into a doubly linked list

Comment: Thanks inspectorG4dget, what I need is given time `O(n)`, is there a way to use less than `O(n)` space?

Comment: BTW, inspectorG4dget, your solution is `O(n^2)` time complexity, I need time complexity of `O(n)` and at the same time space complexity less than `O(n)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you use a double linked list than you have to add the n back references this means you nead additional O(n) space and not 0 space,

Comment: @miracle173: using a doubly linked list does not cost linear space, as it is a property of the data structure to contain those back links. While the doubly linked list will indeed consume one linear order of space more than a singly linked list, a function to print such a doubly linked list in reverse order will not require linear space.

Comment: It's misleading to say "0 space" - it's not zero (the variables are right there in the code!), so it would be much more accurate to say O(1).

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, your solution is O(n^2) time complexity correct?

Comment: Actually it turned out that a double linked list does not necessarily "will indeed consume one linear order of space more than a singly linked list" https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.std.c++/GmxIRWClwkY/qRCDEsNgI6kJ  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list

Answer (score 2):

To long for a comment:

The running time of the algorithm in the OP isn't O(n). It is O(n log(n)). As running time we define the number of times we fecht the next node of a node. This is done explicitely at 3 places in the body of the method reverse_print. Actually it is done at 5 places: 2 in the while-clause and 3 in the body of the while looop, but it can be reduced to 3 if one temporary saves the values. The while loop is repeated about n/2 times. So the reverse_print method fetches the next node 3/2*2 times explicitely. It fetches them implicitely in the two calls of reverse_print after the while loop. The length of the list to process in these calls is half the length of the list used for the original call of reverse_print, so it is n/2. So we have the following approximation for the running time:

```
t(n) = 1.5n+2t(n/2)
```

The solution of this recurrence is

```
t(n) = 1.5n log(n) + n
```

You can verify this if you plug in the solution into the reccurence.

You also can run the problem an count how often a a node is fetched. For this I added a next_node() method to your program. I used the cProfiler to count the function calls. I also added a class method to create a test list. Finally in ended with this program

```
import cProfile
import math

class LinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, value, next_node):
        self.value = value
        self._next_node = next_node

    def next_node(self):
        ''' fetch the next node'''
        return(self._next_node)

    def reverse_print(self, list_tail):
        list_head=self
        if not self:
            return
        if not self.next_node():
            print (self.value)
            return
        if self == list_tail:
            print (self.value)
            return
        p0 = self
        p1 = self
        #assert(p1.next_node != list_tail)
        p1_next=p1.next_node()
        p1_next_next=p1_next.next_node()
        while p1_next != list_tail and p1_next_next != list_tail:
            p1 = p1_next_next
            p0 = p0.next_node()
            p1_next=p1.next_node()
            if p1_next != list_tail:
                p1_next_next=p1_next.next_node()          
        p0.next_node().reverse_print(list_tail)
        self.reverse_print(p0)

    @classmethod
    def create_testlist(nodeclass, n):
        ''' creates a list of n elements with values 1,...,n'''
        first_node=nodeclass(n,None)
        for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
            second_node=first_node
            first_node=nodeclass(i,second_node)
        return(first_node)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n=1000
    cProfile.run('LinkedListNode.create_testlist(n).reverse_print(None)')
    print('estimated number of calls of next_node',1.5*n*math.log(n,2)+n)
```

I got the following output (at the end is the output of the profiler that shows the number of function calls):

```
>>> 
 RESTART: print_reversed_list2.py 
1000
999
998
...
2
1
         116221 function calls (114223 primitive calls) in 2.539 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.539    2.539 <string>:1(<module>)
     2000    0.015    0.000    2.524    0.001 PyShell.py:1335(write)
   1999/1    0.008    0.000    2.538    2.538 print_reversed_list2.py:12(reverse_print)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 print_reversed_list2.py:36(create_testlist)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 print_reversed_list2.py:5(__init__)
    16410    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 print_reversed_list2.py:9(next_node)
   ...

estimated number of calls of next_node 15948.67642699313
```

So the number of next_node() calls estimated by the formula is about 15949. The actual number of  next_node() calls is 16410. The latter number includes the 2000 calls of next_node() of the line `p0.next_node().reverse_print(list_tail)` that I did not count in my formula.

Therefore  `1.5*n*log(n)+n` seems to be a reasonable  estimate for the run time of your program.

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer:** I missed that the list can not be modified in the context of this discussion.

---

**Idea:** We iterate over the list in forward order, reversing it while we are at it. When we reach the end, we iterate backwards, printing elements and reversing the list again.
The core observation is that you can reverse a list in-place: all you need is to remember the last element you handeled.

Untested, ugly pseudo-code:

```scala
def printReverse(list) {
    prev = nil
    cur  = list.head

    if cur == nil {
        return
    }

    while cur != nil {
        next = cur.next
        // [prev]    cur -> next
        cur.next = prev
        // [prev] <- cur    next
        prev = cur
        // [____] <- prev   next
        cur = next
        // [____] <- prev   cur
    }

    // Now cur is nil and prev the last element!

    cur = prev
    prev = nil
    while cur != nil {
        print cur
        // Rewire just as above:
        next = cur.next
        cur.next = prev
        prev = cur
        cur = next
    }
}
```

Clearly, this runs in time O(n) and takes only O(1) (additional) space (three local pointer/reference variables).